# How do I find the number of times an array of characters appers in another array of characters?

Tags: c++

I'm given 2 arrays `sir` and `sub`. I'm supposed to find the number of times `sub` is contained in `sir` by using the `strstr` function in library `<cstring>` and deleting the first letter. For example, `sir` is `omtatatatarshta` and `sub` is `tat`. I can see that `sub` first appears biginning with the third letter and I delete that letter from `sir` so next time I search for `sub` in `sir` I get a different appearence. But I get very confused with managing the fact that `x`, where `x=strstr(sir, sub);`, is a pointer.
`nr` is the variable that shows the number of times `sub` can be found `sir`.

First I've tried to do a `for` like this:
`for(i=x; i<strlen(sir); i++) sir[i]=sir[i+1];` and I got the error `invalid comparison between 'char*' to 'int'`. Then, after looking at some code on the internet I tried writing it like this: `for(char *x; *x!='\0'; *x++) *x=*(x+1);` I got no error with this but I don't get any result either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
ifstream f("info.in");
char sub[20], sir[100];
char* x;
int main()
{
    int nr=0, i;
    f >> sub;
    f >> sir;
    cout << sir;
    x = strstr(sir, sub);
    while (x) {
        nr++;
        for (char* x; *x != '\0'; *x++)
            *x = *(x + 1);
        x = strstr(sir, sub);
    }
    cout << nr;
    return 0;
}
```

In my examples `sub` is `tat` and `sir` is `omtatatatarshta`and the answer should be 3, as you can find `tat` in `omtatatatarshta` three times.
As I've said, I get no result with my code.

Comment: To begin with, where are you learning to program? Who taught you to use global variables? And who taught you how to initialize your local variables (like `nr`)? Because uninitialized local non-static variables *are* uninitialized, and will have an *indeterminate* value (that can be seen as either random or garbage). Lastly, you really need to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: And your reuse of the variable name `x` makes your code hard to read and understand. Apparently even for yourself (as it plays a major part of your problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've modified the program to initialize `nr`, I'm sorry i posted such a bad code. I'm learning to code in school, I'm in my senior year of high school now and this is my homework. Note that my teacher demands that I 
 solve this problem using the method I described (using `strstr` and deleting the first letter). The problem is we haven't really worked with pointers and arrays of characters that much and I can' t seem to find anything to help me with this problem on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with C strings in C++ is possible but not recommended. Managing storage of C strings and processing them is not that easy and error prone.

C++ has a nice replacement for this: **[`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)**. It provides similar features but takes the burden of memory management from application programmer.

Why ever OPs teacher sticks to teach C string processing... [Kate Gregory: Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk).

This being said, I don't get why OP believes there must be something deleted in `sir`. The "strength" of a C string is – it just begins there a `char*` points to. If that pointer is incremented n times the string just begins n `char`s later. (Of course, you have to care about the 0 terminator. Moving the pointer behind it may lead into Undefined Behavior.)

So, that's how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char *const sir = "omtatatatarshta";
    const char *const sub = "tat";
    int nr = 0;
    for (const char *x = sir;; ++nr) {
      x = strstr(x, sub);
      if (!x) break;
      ++x; // inc. x to prevent double matching the same
    }
    std::cout << "nr: " << nr << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
nr: 3
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab9f1d0d810a449c)</kbd>

Looking at OPs exposed code, I assume there is still mis-understanding how pointers work. (I remember I needed a while as well to understand them.)

```
for (char* x; *x != '\0'; *x++)
        *x = *(x + 1);
```

This is broken.

1. `for (char *x;` ... introduces a new local variable `x` existing only in `for` loop. The already existing `x` is eclipsed. (It's still there but not accessible inside of `for` loop.)
2. `for (char *x;` declares `x` but does not define it – it's uninitialized. As `x` may have any arbitrary contents i.e. it can point to anywhere. Hence, read contents of `x` is Undefined Behavior (bad).
3. `for (char* x; *x != '\0'; *x++)`: `*x++` "reads" contents of `x` and increments pointer `x` afterwards. It's not directly an error but there is no reason to read contents of `x`. `x++` (or even better `++x`) would have been sufficient.

I fixed this code to (what I believe) OP intended to do:

for (; *x != '\0'; ++x) *x = *(x + 1);

Furthermore, I added some print-Debugging to make visual what happens inside:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char sir[] = "omtatatatarshta";
    const char *const sub = "tat";
    int nr = 0;
    std::cout << "sir: '" << sir << "'\n";
    char *x = strstr(sir, sub);
    while (x) {
      ++nr;
      std::cout << "Hit " << nr << '\n';
      for (; *x != '\0'; ++x) *x = *(x + 1);
      std::cout << "sir: '" << sir << "'\n";
      x = strstr(sir, sub);
    }
    std::cout << "nr: " << nr << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sir: 'omtatatatarshta'
nr: 1
sir: 'omatatatarshta'
nr: 2
sir: 'omaatatarshta'
nr: 3
sir: 'omaaatarshta'
nr: 3
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/866e9cb47016f8bc)</kbd>

**Note:**

Please, note the difference of how I declared `sir` in first and second example.

In first example: `const char *const sir = "omtatatatarshta";`

`sir` is a `const` pointer (due to the `*const`) to a `const char`. The declaration forces that neither the pointer nor the contents may be changed. The pointer is initialized with the address of constant string `"omtatatatarshta"`.

In opposition to this, the `x` has type `const char*`. It's a non-constant pointer to constant contents. Contents is not touched, hence it can be restricted to read-only. Pointer is assigned (by `strstr()`). Hence it may not be `const`.

In the second example: `char sir[] = "omtatatatarshta";`.

As the contents of `sir` shall be changed, it must be an array.